# форматирование текста в форме

Tags: html, css

здравствуйте!
у меня такой вопрос: делаю элементы формы: checkbox и radio, при однострочной подписи все нормально, а при многострочной - все выглядит убого.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы текст ВЕСЬ выравнивался по Lorem Ipsum, а не залезал под checkbox? Как в Worde
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую элементы input type="checkbox" и label

Comment: Кидайте код сюда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу только такой выход:

```
<style>
input,label{
    float:left;
}
input{
    width: 20px;
}
label{
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
<input id="1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="1">qwerqwerqwer qewrqwerer ewrqwerqwerqwer werqwerqwe rqwer qwer qwe rqw er erererqewrqwerq ewrqwerqwerqwerqwerqwe r</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o82s8wzc/

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!! ЗАРАБОТАЛО!=))))))

Comment: @Мария, если заработало, то ответ следует отметить как решение вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не ограничивать `label` фиксированной шириной можно решить вопрос более правильно: поместить `input` в `label` и задать правильное позиционирование и отступы.

Пример смотрите ниже.

```css
label {
  padding-left: 26px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
  has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</label>
<label for="checkbox-2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</label>
<label for="checkbox-3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
  has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</label>
```

Comment: Полностью согласен! @Мария, стоит пере-отметить, если тут так можно делать.